# 2D array print error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This is my code snippet:

```
float *fittedLine[NO_OF_INTERVALS];
int i;
for(k=0;k<NO_OF_INTERVALS;k++){
    fittedLine[k] = plotLines(tStart, tEnd, yStart, yEnd);
    for(i=0;i<14;i++)
        printf("%f\n", fittedLine[k][i]);
}
```

My problem: The print statement is not giving proper outputs; Garbage values are printed.

I tried debugging by putting a breakpoint in line 5 and tried printing 
fittedLine[0][0], fittedLine[0][1] and so on.
**That gives proper output**. But when coming to the print statement, things start to fall apart. What is happening here? plotLines returns a 1D array.

plotLines function:

```
float * plotLines(float t0, float tf, float y0, float yf){
    float m = (yf - y0)/(tf - t0);
    float t = t0;
    int i = 0;
    float y[200];
    while(t<tf){
        y[i] = m*t + yf - m*tf; ///y - y1 = m(x - x1)
        i++;
        t = t+SAMPLINGTIME;
    }
    return y;
```

}

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. And describe what "proper output" is supposed to be.

Comment: Show the `plotLines` function.

Comment: you have not allocated any memory for your pointer variable `fittedLine`!

Comment: @kaylum:Sorry, but how can you presume what `plotLines` function does?

Comment: @user1336087: could please you show how I would do that?

Comment: @kaylum: Now that you have seen the `plotLines` you can understand memory allocation was the problem. Otherwise where else the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to see the `plotLines` function, but my *guess* is that you are returning a local variable:

```
float *plotLines() {
   float temp[14];
   // blah...
   return temp;
}
```

This is bad. `temp` goes out of scope when the function ends. You need to allocate the array using `malloc` and return that pointer:

```
float *plotLines() {
   float *temp = malloc(sizeof(float) * 14);
   // Make sure temp is not NULL
   // blah...
   return temp;
}
```

Don't forget to `free` all that memory later. If you only use the results temporarily, a `static` array could work:

```
float *plotLines() {
   static float temp[14];
   // blah...
   return temp;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Exactly as you guessed.

Comment: @kaylum I see OP finally posted code. Guess my crystal ball was working today.